# Django. Can't acces to media files with media_url

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have problems with media files. 
In my models.py I can upload a file without problems with mapa = models.FileField(upload_to='zones/osm'). This puts the file into media/zones/osm/. But when I trying to acces the file from views.py I get this: Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/zones/osm/prova1.osm'

Can anybody say me waths is wrong? Here is my configuration:

Directory structure:

```
tottrack/
    media/  
        zones/
            osm/
    principal/
        views.py
        models.py
    tottrack/
        settings.py
```

settings.py:

```
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH,'..')
DEBUG = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

url.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:    
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True }),    
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
)
```

Views.py:

```
c = City('/media/zones/osm/prova1.osm') #City() it's a method from a custom python library.
```

It could be a problem of my library? If I miss something tell me please! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You use absolute path to file (it starts with `/`), which mean it search it from file system root, not relative to media dir.)

If your custom `City` does not know anything about django internals, you need provide it full path to file `/home/User/projects/bla-bla/media/zones/osm/prova1.osm`

Comment: Thanks! But there is no way to do taht with relative paths?